# Get grouped HTML data to PHP array? (Like sub-elements of checkbox)

Tags: php, html, arrays

How to convert this form structure to a PHP array? I can also edit HTML, so every idea is good...

[image]

If a checkbox is checked then this data is to push into a PHP array by saving, needed structure is:

```
0 =>
   'group' => 'group_a',
   'type' => 'type_yellow',
   'desc' => 'now to convert'
1 =>
   'group' => 'group_b',
   'type' => 'type_orange',
   'desc' => 'needed to order'
```

As example what I tried is to give by `input` element name as `array` like `description[]` but I cannot control if a checkbox is checked or not...

Comment: Maybe you could name the input fields like: `entries[][group]`, `entries[][type]`, `entries[][desc]`

Comment: What problem are you having with writing the code? Readers like to see a prior effort here, so they can help you where you are stuck. Stack Overflow is not a site where code is written by volunteers, from scratch, to order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. For checkboxes, standard behaviour is the value is only sent if the checkbox is checked. So, a server side solution for this could be:

Firstly, Name the input fields as follows:

- `entries[][group]`
- `entries[][type]`
- `entries[][desc]`

Or, alternatively

- `entries[0][group]`
- `entries[0][type]`
- `entries[0][desc]`
- `entries[1][group]`
- `entries[1][type]`
- `entries[1][desc]`
- and so on....

The values will be available as an array in `$_POST[entries]`, if you are using `POST` method.

```
$entries = $_POST['entries'];
```

Now, we need to filter out `entries` for which it's corresponding checkbox is unchecked. We can use `array_filter` for that:

```
$entries = array_filter($entries, function($entry) {
    return isset($entry['group']);
});
```

Comment: Nice solution. That should give the OP the exact structure they want.

Comment: @Jomoos so I can make my structure as wanted, problem is solved with your `name` structure. Thank you very much